# Why does my ViewCell's label text disappear at small row heights in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to shrink the row size of a ListView in Xamarin that has so far been pretty reliable. The items look like this right now:

[image]

However, I now want to shrink them. I adjust the row height, and I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have the property HasUnevenRows set to true, which seems to be what most questions advise. I have also read about bugs with the ListView on UWP: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48428. But I'm developing for Android. Am I missing something fundamental here? Because this doesn't seem as intuitive as it should.

Here is my XAML:

```
               <ListView 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SummaryItems}"
                  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  RowHeight="50" 
                  BackgroundColor="LightGray" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <Frame CornerRadius="2.5" Margin="0, 1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="test"  />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Item2}"  />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Item3}"  />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Item4}"  />
                                    <Label Grid.Column="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Item5}"  />
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Frame` has built-in padding, so set the `Padding` to 0 and it should work as long as the text can fit at all.

Comment: Ivan, that did it. Thank you so much. It's in the docs as well "Frame have a default Padding of 20." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame?view=xamarin-forms. But I'm not sure it's obvious enough! I guess a frame _is_ a frame though.